What is the approximate number of followers of different Vishnuist sects today?
Only Vishnuist sects have significant following today.
Madhwists claim they are around 2 million now.
Srivaishnavites can be estimated at a similar number (based on a percentage of Tamil Nadu's population.)
is anything known about how many Gaudiyas, ISKCON followers, Swaminarayan followers et al are there?
Is it known which sects are growing, declining or are stable?
